# How to implement Login with Google in UWP apps?

Tags: authentication

How to implement Login with Google in UWP apps?

I need help to implement Login with google feature in UWP apps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use google credentials to login into UWP C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948054/use-google-credentials-to-login-into-uwp-c-sharp-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to accomplish, I would suggest using [OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).As you can see there, support is provided for Java, .NET, Python, Ruby, JS, etc.  For collecting authentication information I used a WebView.